# Importing SHP to Oracle -

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial, windows, osgeo4w

I'm trying to import a SHP to my Oracle database.

I've installed OSGeo4W (Express Install with all 4 packages).

After running my command

`.\ogr2ogr.exe -f "OCI" "OCI:user/pass@192.168.1.87/n2012" D:\data\nr.shp -update -lco PRECISION=NO -overwrite -nln XF_NR`

I've got an error

`Unable to find driver OCI'`

I have and older version of OSGeo4W (folder is named OSGeo4W64, in the new istalation it's just OSGeo4W) installed on an other computer and it works fine. I just noticed some directory and files have changed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you install the Oracle driver when you installed OSGeo4W? I don't think is part of the standard install

Comment: What do you mean by Oracle driver ? How is it called ?

Comment: It is called "OCI" https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oci.html. In the OSGeo4W setup it is named as "gdal-oracle".